# HTML5 Canvas stationary line draw

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have a canvas where I'm drawing a line using setInterval so it's animated. Right now it starts at 20,20 and end the animation at 200,20. Ideally I'd want the point on the canvas to never move, so it would look like the line is drawing but the canvas is moving. Best example would be a car that is driving that stays in frame while the background moves or think Mission Impossible where you follow the burning fuse as it burns.

is there a method to move the whole line? This way I can move the line to the left as I add to the line. If not would it be better to make a huge canvas and move it to the left as the line draws? What's the best way to create an animation like this?

Comment: Have a look at translate

Comment: If you're not redrawing the canvas on each animation cycle and simply *adding* to the current canvas, then wouldn't translating the canvas sooner or later move the line off screen? I think in terms of drawing a horizontal line you should stick with the method your using now.

Comment: here's what I'm doing now. Just wasn't sure if there was a method for actually moving the line or if I should use a long horizonal canvas http://jsfiddle.net/u4HgV/5/

Comment: Ok, so if that is the effect you want then yes, you should look into @Neil's comment about the translate method. That will just move the canvas rather than having to move it by its CSS margin.

Comment: Translate looks like it should be able to do it.Thanks everyone